# C++ Multimap insert function

Tags: c++, dictionary, multimap

I am using multimap to store values. I just want to check while inserting in multimap, if the value is success or failure.

I am trying to use the following code

```
if (MultiMap.insert(TypeDefMap::value_type(Id, ans)))
  return 1;
else
  return 0;
```

But this is giving error that scalar types expected.

I think I am missing something silly here. I tried typecasting to int and bool but did not worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you rely on some return value, you should _always_ check the documentation (if you're not sure) what is the returned type and what the value means.

Comment: Arbitrarily guessing at return values is poor form. Trying to hack around errors by blinding typecasting is even worse!

Answer (score 2):

according to the docs (of multimap `insert` method)

> In the versions returning a value,
>   this is an iterator pointing to the
>   newly inserted element in the
>   multimap.

you should check if that iterator != end() means success, otherwise, failure.

Comment: Actually, you should check if the iterator is `end()`. That is not the same as being valid.

Comment: Actually, it will never be `end()`.

Answer (score 1):

The only two things that can fail in `std::mutlimap::insert` are:

- Allocation fails, but that throws `std::bad_alloc` exception.
- The comparator for key throws an exception, but that exception would be propagated.

(plus some undefined behaviours like calling it on uninitialized instance/bad pointer/..., but that will probably give you a segmentation fault anyway). Since neither returns anything, there is no point in checking whether it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

multimap::insert returns an iterator that points to the newly inserted element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(MultiMap.insert(TypeDefMap::value_type(Id, ans)) == MultiMap.end())
    return FAILURE
else
    return SUCCESS
```

Any returns from the map/set/multimap/multiset, if is iterator, if invalid it should be equal to end().